# Django - make_random_password method, is it truly random?

Tags: python, django, random

I am using the following method to create a random code for users as part of a booking process:

```
 User.objects.make_random_password()
```

When the users turn up at the venue, they will present the password.

Is it safe to assume that two people won't end up with the same code?

Comment: The title asks about randomness, while content asks about uniqueness. These are completely different concepts.

Comment: @Tadeck Thanks for the clarification, appreciate it!

Comment: @Tadeck I totally disagree with you. Those aren't completely different concepts. They go side by side. If something is not random enough than uniqueness can't be guaranteed. I think the question makes sense.

Comment: In addition, the question you're asking here, if you look in depth, it's a problem in mathematics too.

Comment: @PatrickBassut: To support my point (that randomness is separate from uniqueness), I recommend you read this: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/3188/5178 - they probably better explain the differences. One example against your " _If something is not random enough than uniqueness can't be guaranteed_ " is [A000027 sequence](https://oeis.org/A000027), which is definitely **not random**, and every item is **guaranteed to be unique** (this is why it is being used very often to guarantee uniqueness of primary key in many RDBMSs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not safe to assume that two people can't have the same code.  Random doesn't mean unique.  It may be unlikely and rare, depending on the length you specify and number of users you are dealing with.  But you can't rely on its uniqueness.

Comment: Also, if you really do want uniqueness, you could use a combination of randomly generated string with a counter value added to the end, which gets incremented each time you add a user.  If the width of that counter is large enough to counter your users, then you are guaranteed uniqueness.

Comment: I get the concept of incrementing by 1 each time I add a user but what do you mean by "width of that counter is large enough to counter your users". Could you please elaborate? Much appreciated.

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the password generation algorithm. It essentially already does what you suggest by re-seeding the PRNG every call with the current time and the current state. See my answer.

Comment: By counter width I just meant if you use a 16-bit counter, then you can only count to 65,535 or a 32-bit counter will give you 2^32 combinations, etc.  So you would need to make sure your counter is big enough to count the number of users.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on now many users you have, and the password length you choose, and how you use `User.objects.make_random_password()` For the defaults, the chance is essentially zero, IMO;

This method is implemented using [`get_random_string()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3174b5f2f5bb0b0a6b775a1a50464b6bf2a4b067/django/utils/crypto.py). From the django github repo:

```
def get_random_string(length=12,
                      allowed_chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                                    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'):
    """
Returns a securely generated random string.

The default length of 12 with the a-z, A-Z, 0-9 character set returns
a 71-bit value. log_2((26+26+10)^12) =~ 71 bits
"""
    if not using_sysrandom:
        # This is ugly, and a hack, but it makes things better than
        # the alternative of predictability. This re-seeds the PRNG
        # using a value that is hard for an attacker to predict, every
        # time a random string is required. This may change the
        # properties of the chosen random sequence slightly, but this
        # is better than absolute predictability.
        random.seed(
            hashlib.sha256(
                "%s%s%s" % (
                    random.getstate(),
                    time.time(),
                    settings.SECRET_KEY)
                ).digest())
    return ''.join([random.choice(allowed_chars) for i in range(length)])
```

According to github, the current code uses a 12 character password from a string of 62 characters (lower- and uppercase letters and numbers) by default. This makes for 62**12 or 3226266762397899821056 (3.22e21) possible different passwords. This is *much* larger than the current world population (around 7e9).

The letters are picked from this list of characters by the `random.choice()` function. The question now becomes how likely it is that the repeated calling of `random.choice()` returns the same sequence twice?

As you can see from the implementation of `get_random_string()`, the code tries hard to avoid predictability. When not using the OS's pseudo-random value generator (which on Linux and *BSD gathers real randomness from e.g. the times at which ethernet packets or keypresses arrive), it re-seeds the [`random`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) module's [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) predictable PRNG at each call with a combination of the current random state, the current time and (presumably constant) secret key.

So for two identical passwords to be generated, both the state of the random generator (which is about 8 kiB in python) and the time at which they are generated (measured in seconds since the epoch, as per `time.time()`) have to be identical. If the system's time is well-maintained and you are running one instance of the password generation program, the chance of that happening is essentially zero. If you start two or more instances of this password generating program at *exactly* the same time and with *exactly* the same seed for the PRNG, and combine their output, one would expect some passwords to appear more than once.